# JPA 2.0 native query results as map

Tags: jpa, native

I run a JPA 2.0 native query like this:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT NAME, SURNAME, AGE FROM PERSON");
List list = query.getResultList();
```

now `list` has all the rows returned by the query. I can iterate over them, but every entry is an `Object[]` where:

> - at index 0 I find NAME
> - at index 1 I find SURNAME
> - at index 3 I find AGE

Did anyone find a way to do something like this:

```
Map<String, Object> row = list.get(index);
String name = row.get("NAME");
String surname = row.get("SURNAME");
Integer age = row.get("AGE");
```

I would need this since the native query that I execute is a dynamic one and I don't know the order of the field in SELECT clause, so I don't know id the query will look like:

```
SELECT SURNAME, NAME, AGE FROM PERSON
```

or

```
SELECT AGE, NAME, SURNAME FROM PERSON
```

or even

```
SELECT AGE, SURNAME, NAME FROM PERSON
```

Comment: criteria query ? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/

Comment: I don't think so, becase I'd still need Person.class behind. As I said the SQL qeury is dynamic and I actually don't know what it will look like.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Which JPA are you using - Hibernate, EclipseLink or something else?

There is no standard way to do this in JPA but your specific implementation may allow it - for example, Eclipselink has a query result type hint.

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg03013.html

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
query.setHint(QueryHints.RESULT_TYPE, ResultType.Map);
```

For Hibernate, with javax.persistence.Query dbQuery:

```
org.hibernate.Query hibernateQuery =((org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateQuery)dbQuery)
.getHibernateQuery();
hibernateQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: it appears hibernate does not have such a hint :(

Comment: It is working for me using native query like this : 
`NativeQueryImpl nativeQuery = (NativeQueryImpl) query;`
 `nativeQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);`
`List<Map<String,Object>> result =  query.getResultList();`
`Map<String, Object> row = result.get(0);`
   String value = (String) row.get("NAME");

Comment: The method setResultTransformer() is deprecated since Hibernate 5.2

Answer (score 6):

As other already mentioned, older `JPA` does not support it, however I have workaround solution with `Postgres 9.4` in my situation, while working with `Jackson`,

```
List<String> list = em.createNativeQuery("select cast(json_object_agg(c.config_key,c.config_value) as text) from myschema.configuration c")
                   .getResultList();
```

To use it in Bean layer use below method, otherwise directly return.

```
//handle exception here, this is just sample
Map map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(list.get(0), Map.class);
```

Few more json functions, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html. I am sure you can find same for other databases.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on this I got it when working on project that I could not use all JPA features so I tried the traditional jdbc method even if I would not recommend this but it's working for me.

```
@LocalBean
public class TCotisationEJB {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="ClaimsProjectPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
    public List getCotisation(){
        Query query=em.createNativeQuery("select Annee,Mois,RetSonarwa from TCotisMIFOTRA2008 where matricule='10000493' order by Annee");
        List<Object[]> cotisation=query.getResultList();
        Object[] cotisationData;

         for(int i=0;i<cotisation.size();i++){
              cotisationData=cotisation.get(i);

             System.out.print("Annee: "+cotisationData[0]+" Mois :"+cotisationData[1]+" Amount       :"+cotisationData[2]+"\n");

     }  
     return query.getResultList();
     }    
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what OP wants to change.