# Return a subset of a JPA entity as a array of maps from a JPQL query?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

In JPQL it is possible to ask for a subset of an entity using a constructor expression such as

```
SELECT NEW example.EmployeeDetails(e.name, e.salary, e.department.name) FROM Employee e
```

which returns a list of objects of type EmployeeDetails

or using a projection select such as

```
SELECT e.name, e.salary FROM Employee e
```

which returns an `Object[] result` where result[0] is e.name and result[1] is e.salary

is there a way to get JPA to return a Map which contains a subset of the entity for example is there a JPQL query that can return  `List<Map<String,Object>> result` such that `result.get(0).get("e.name")` return `e.name` and `result.get(0).get('e.salary')` return `e.salary`

If JPQL can't do it does can HQL do it?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595328/jpa-2-0-native-query-results-as-map/46190527#46190527

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JPA provides limited amount of [return types for compound selection](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#SELECT_in_Criteria_Queries_): array, tuple and construct, while Hibernate provides much more [return types for select clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-select), which includes Map.

```
SELECT NEW map(e.name, e.salary, e.department.name) FROM Employee e
```

This HQL query returns a `Map` from aliases to selected values.

Comment: Why where is no Spring Data HQL?