# how to map query result to string array in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, orm

```
select id,name,salary,city,state,country from employee where name like '%a%';
```

I need to map above query result to String array, position 0 always id, position 1 always  name ...... position 5 always  country.

Using JPA or MyBatis is there a way we can dynamically map the select query values into fixed position string array ?

Comment: Yes, that would be the default result with JPA. Why don't you... try?

Comment: @JBNizet so far I used to map for employee object, I need to may now string array, could you please share small example

Comment: there is so many ways to go about this. it would be hugely helpful you posted what you have attempted or trying to do.

Comment: @jpganz18 & denov
similar to the above scenario I have to map 100 + query results, each query select fields are different very few are common between the queries and number select columns for each query varies, altogether 400 - 500 columns. don't want to create a class for each query, so thinking to add index-based. Don't want to iterate and add values to the array, so looking is there a way I could map directly columns to the array.
List<String[]> array will have column values, the list will have row values.

Comment: check this code and give it a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595328/jpa-2-0-native-query-results-as-map/46190527#46190527

Answer (score 0):

I've never personally used JPA, but - after reading through it a bit - believe this *should* be correct.

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = entityManager.createQuery(
  "SELECT id,name,salary,city,state,country FROM employee WHERE name LIKE '%a%'", Object[].class);
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
```

where (Integer) results.get(index)[0] = id, (String) results.get(index)[1] = name, etc.

You can change Object[] to String[] if you would like an array of Strings.

Comment: please see my above comments, hope that answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use String array?

It is better to use an object list instead. It will be easier to get city of an employee using `employee.getCity()` versus `array[3]`.

It makes for more readable code as well.

To use an object list, you need to create a model for your employee and annotate with @Entity and create a repository for that entity. JPA documentation should help do this easily

Comment: similar to the above scenario I have to map 100 + query results, each query select fields are different very few are common between the queries and number select columns for each query varies, altogether 400 - 500 columns. don't want to create a class for each query, so thinking to add index-based. Don't want to iterate and add values to the array, so looking is there a way I could map directly columns to the array.
List<String[]> array will have column values, the list will have row values.

Comment: if that is what you want, it should be straight forward using resultSet. just do `stringArray[i] = resultSet.get(i)`