# Convert Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> to HashMap<K, V>

Tags: java, dictionary, set

At one point in my code, I created a `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>>` from a map. Now I want to recreate the same map form, so I want to convert the `HashSet<Map.Entry<K, V>>` back into a `HashMap<K, V>`. Does Java have a native call for doing this, or do I have to loop over the set elements and build the map up manually?

Comment: How did you created `Set` from `Map`, using key or value or custom logic? besides there is no `native` method for `HashSet` to `HashMap`. You need to iterate and use some logic as while putting into `HashMap` how you choose key and value.

Comment: @Paul thanks now question makes clear sense

Comment: I don't think `Map.Entry` is meant to be used this way. Does the implementation used by `HashMap` override `hashCode` and `equals` for example?

Comment: a Set of Map.Entry IS a Map (logically). The implementation of TreeSet/HashSet is to use a tree/hash map to backup the set. 

Meaning Set.add(X) == Map.put(X,whatever);

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no inbuilt API in java for direct conversion between `HashSet` and `HashMap`, you need to iterate through set and using `Entry` fill in map.

one approach:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    //fill in map
    Set<Entry<Integer, String>> set = map.entrySet();

    Map<Integer, String> mapFromSet = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    for(Entry<Integer, String> entry : set)
    {
        mapFromSet.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
```

Though what is the purpose here, if you do any changes in `Set` that will also reflect in `Map` as set returned by `Map.entrySet` is backup by `Map`. See `javadoc` below:

> Set<Entry<Integer, String>> java.util.Map.entrySet()
>
> Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map. The set is
>   backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and
>   vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is
>   in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation, or
>   through the setValue operation on a map entry returned by the
>   iterator) the results of the iteration are undefined. The set supports
>   element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map,
>   via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear
>   operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.

Answer (score 89):

Simpler Java-8 solution involving `Collectors.toMap`:

```
Map<Integer, String> mapFromSet = set.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

An `IllegalStateException` will be thrown if duplicate key is encountered.

Comment: what aboug NPEs if any value is null?

Answer (score 9):

Fairly short Java 8 solution. Can cope with duplicate keys.

```
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    //fill in map
    Set<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> set = map.entrySet();
    Map<Integer, String> mapFromSet = set.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
      Entry::getValue,
      (a,b)->b));
```

Edit: thanks to [shmosel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553851/shmosel) who deserves more credit than I do for this

Comment: No.  Your BiConsumer does not combine the Maps.

Comment: In the above code, the BiConsumer's accept method is never called. I would have preferred to use null but the collect method stupidly throws an  NPE in that case.

Comment: @mikeyreilly, [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) does not explicitly say that the combiner is never called for sequential stream. Thus you just violate the contract of the method.

Comment: @TagirValeev A fair point, but I'd rather violate the contract than write code that does nothing

Comment: Ok, you guys, I feel bad about breaking the contract. I've amended my solution.

Comment: You could just as easily use `Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> b)`.

Answer (score 9):

As of Guava 19 you can use [`ImmutableMap.copyOf(Iterable<Map.Entry<K,V>>)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#copyOf-java.lang.Iterable-)

Answer (score 7):

#### Java 9+ without suppressed warning

As of the Java 9 version, the collection interfaces provide a bunch of handy static methods allowing you to do a lot of things inline. There is a built-in solution using a static method [`Map.ofEntries(Map.Entry... entries)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries-java.util.Map.Entry...-) which creates an immutable map.

```
Map<Integer,String> map = Map.ofEntries(
        new SimpleEntry<>(1, "one"), 
        new SimpleEntry<>(2, "two"), 
        new SimpleEntry<>(3, "three"));
```

Note that also the [`Map.entry(K, V)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-) method is available which makes everything less verbose.

```
Map<Integer,String> map2 = Map.ofEntries(
        Map.entry(1, "one"), 
        Map.entry(2, "two"), 
        Map.entry(3, "three"));
```

Assuming you have `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>>`, you need an array to use the method using [`Set#toArray(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray-T:A-). Explicit casting is required due to forbidden generic array creation, which is the only drawback of this solution.

```
Set<Map.Entry<Integer,String>> set = ...
Entry<Integer, String>[] entries = set.<Entry<Integer,String>>toArray(Entry[]::new);
Map<Integer,String> map = Map.ofEntries(entries);
```

#### Java 8

Java 8 brings Stream API which is pretty straightforward using [`Collectors.toMap(keyFn, valueFn)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html).

```
Set<Map.Entry<Integer,String>> set = ...
Map<Integer,String> map = set.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Entry::getKey,
            Entry::getValue));
```

To avoid erroneous behavior in the presence of two `Map.Entry` with the same keys that are forbidden in dictionaries, use [`Collectors.toMap(keyFn, valueFn, mergeFn)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-). Return either `first` or `second` depending on if you want to keep the first value found for a certain key or the latest one.

```
Map<Integer,String> map = set.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Entry::getKey, 
            Entry::getValue,
            (first, second) -> first));  // if you need the 1st occurrence
         // (first, second) -> second)); // if you need the last occurrence
```

#### Java 7 and older

All, you can do is a procedural for-each iteration as the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16108889/3764965) describes.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2018, there are some `toMap` utility in Apache libraries, but unfortunately most of them take an array instead of `Set`, so you need to do [`Set#toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray--) first.

I left [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#copyOf-java.lang.Iterable-) out for [@Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44904884/188256) which is arguably the best.

### Apache Commons Collections' [MapUtils.putAll](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.0/org/apache/commons/collections4/MapUtils.html#putAll%28java.util.Map,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

```java
Map<K, V> map = MapUtils.putAll(new HashMap<K, V>(), entrySet.toArray());
```

### Apache Commons Collections' [MapUtils.populateMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.0/org/apache/commons/collections4/MapUtils.html#populateMap(java.util.Map,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20org.apache.commons.collections4.Transformer,%20org.apache.commons.collections4.Transformer))

```java
HashMap<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
MapUtils.populateMap(map, entrySet, Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue);
```

### Apache Commons Lang's [ArrayUtils.toMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.7/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toMap-java.lang.Object:A-)

```java
Map<Object, Object> map = ArrayUtils.toMap(entrySet.toArray());

// to recover the type...
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<K, V> typedMap = (Map<K, V>)(Map<?, ?>)map;
```

### Java 9's [Map.ofEntries](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries-java.util.Map.Entry...-)

```java
 // convert to array and recover the type...
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 Map<K, V> map = Map.ofEntries(entrySet.toArray(new Map.Entry[0]));

 // You need to copy again if you want a mutable one
 Map<K, V> hashmap = new HashMap<>(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 with correct combiner

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
//fill in map
Set<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> set = map.entrySet();

Map<Integer, String> mapFromSet =set.stream().collect(HashMap::new,(t, u) -> t.put(u.getKey(), u.getValue()), 
(Map mapToReturn, Map otherMap) ->
    {
        otherMap.entrySet().forEach((Map.Entry entry) -> {
            mapToReturn.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
        });
        return mapToReturn;}););
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to try this for a practice problem. My issue was that I needed to convert two "maps" into "sets" so I can use the math operations that come with sets, like Union, Intersection, and Difference. While learning about "Map.Entry" I found I could convert the "Maps" into "Sets" perform the math operation as required. However, I still needed to convert my return value back into a "Map" per problem requirements. I found that I could do this if you typecast the objects back into the original variables. My end result is a "Map" that includes only the Intersections of both Maps.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> intersect(Map<String, Integer> map_one, Map<String, Integer> map_two)
{
    Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> set_one = map_one.entrySet(); //Map one now a set
    Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> set_two = map_two.entrySet(); //Map two now a set
    set_one.retainAll(set_two); //a math intersection operation set_one and set_two whose contents are the intersection of the two sets
    Map<String, Integer> map_retur = new HashMap<>(); //instantiation  of a new Map object
    Iterator i = set_one.iterator(); //instantiation of an iterator
      while(i.hasNext())
      {
         Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next(); // instantiation of Map.Entry as me and convert i into that Map.Entry
         map_retur.put((String)me.getKey(), (Integer)me.getValue()); // store each key/value pair into the Map as required
      }
    return map_retur; // returned value is a map with only the intersections
}
```

**Thanks Ref:** https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_mapentry_interface.html
For how to do the iterations in the for each loop. However, it does not include the typecasting I have shown here.