# How to convert set to map with a set as the value in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following class:

```
class A {
   private String id;
   private String name;
   private String systemid;
}
```

I'm getting a set of A and want to convert it to a map where the key is the system id, and the value is set of A. (`Map<String, Set<A>`)
There can be multiple A instances with the same systemid.

Can't seem to figure out how to do it..
got till here but the identity is clearly not right

```
Map<String, Set<A>> sysUidToAMap = mySet.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getSystemID, Function.identity()));
```

can you please assist?

Comment: see here, this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108734/convert-setmap-entryk-v-to-hashmapk-v

Comment: I want to ask one thing. As you said, you have a `Set<A>` and you want to mapped it `Map<String, Set<A>>`, when you will mapped it, it will contain one value per key, Map<String, A> is useful i think..

Answer (score 12):

You can use `groupingBy` instead of `toMap`:

```
Map<String, Set<A>> sysUidToAMap =  
    mySet.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getSystemID,
                                        Collectors.toSet()));
```

Comment: If you don't really need `Set<A>` for the groups, but can live with `List<A>`, you can leave off the `mapping` stuff and it becomes much more concise. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: @Thilo That's true. I only included the mapping to a Set because that was the desired output in the question.

Comment: @Eran  
I want to ask one thing. we have a Set<A> and we want to mapped it Map<String, Set<A>>, when you will mapped it, it will contain one value per key, Map<String, A> is useful right??

Comment: @SubhabrataMondal: No. There could be multiple entries for the same systemid (we don't know what that is). But if there is "business logic" that makes sure that every systemId appears only once, then, yes, a `Map<String,A>` would be more appropriate (and the conversion code should report unexpected duplicates)

Comment: if my first Set contains 10 elements of A where 5 of them have sysyemid = "1" and the other 5 have systemid="b", then I wanted the map to contain 2 keys, where each value has a set of 5 elements.. so it's not one value per key

Answer (score 3):

my 2¢: you *can* do it with `Collectors.toMap` but it's slightly more verbose:

```
      yourSet
      .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    A::getSystemId,
                    a -> {
                        Set<A> set = new HashSet<>();
                        set.add(a);
                        return set;
                    }, (left, right) -> {
                        left.addAll(right);
                        return left;
                    }));
```

Comment: First, up-vote. what does `0.02$` mean? I have seen you say it several times.

Comment: @holi-java https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_two_cents it sort of mean that this is a very small addition to what has already been said

Comment: And for whatever reason, people like to write `0.02$` instead of `2¢` and sometimes, they even omit the preceding “my”…

Answer (score 2):

As streams were not specifically requested, here's a way to do it only with the `Map` API:

```
Map<String, Set<A>> map = new HashMap<>();
mySet.forEach(a -> map.computeIfAbsent(a.getSystemId(), k -> new HashSet<>()).add(a));
```