# How do I build a Java `Map<K,V>` out of `List<Map.Entry<K,V>>`?

Tags: java

I have a `List<Map.Entry<Long, String>>`.

How do I convert this into a `Map`?

Currently I am doing the following, but it seems a bit verbose (and most importantly, it is not "fluent", i.e. a single expression, but requires a code block).

```
Map<Long, String> result = new HashMap<>();
entries.forEach(e -> result.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
return result;
```

Java 10 is fine.

Comment: I would go with Java 11 as 10 is eol.

Comment: @PeterLawrey  already? Oh my, they are moving fast...

Comment: Java 11 is EOL in 4 months :P At that time many might shift to OpenJDK 11, instead of skipping to 12.  e.g. https://adoptopenjdk.net/

Comment: Anyway, I meant this as in "use of Java 10 API are permissible" (in the hopes that we have something less boilerplatey than the Java 8 streams collectors now). Does Java 11 bring something new to the table here (such as Collection literals)?

Comment: Not really imho, You can write `entries.forEach((var e) -> result.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));` note the `var e`, the real advantage is Long Term Support-ability.

Answer (score 2):

If you know for sure there are no duplicate keys, this is sufficient:

```
Map<Long, String> result = entries.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

If there may be duplicates, you'll have to add a merge function to handle them.

Comment: Hmm. I made it a List of Map.Entry specifically to avoid having to specify again what the `::getKey` and `::getValue` should be, but I guess I'll have to go with that.

Comment: I do like the Guava answer from the duplicate thread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44904884/14955 And `java.util.Map.ofEntries` is close, too, but does not work with a list.

Comment: What happens if I have duplicates but no merge function?

Comment: @Thilo An exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Flatten it:

```
Map<Long, String> result = 
    entries.stream()
        .collect(toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue(), (a, b) -> b);
```

The `(a, b) -> b` means that the last value for duplicate keys will be taken, which matches the semantics of your current approach.

Comment: `Map.Entry` has no method called `entrySet`

Comment: @Ferrybig my mistake, I thought it was a list of maps.