# How to return list of key/value pair maps from JPQL query using EclipseLink?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have tried [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) solution:

```
List<javax.persistence.Tuple> result = entityManager.createQuery("select f.Id as Id, f.Project as Project from FirewallRequest f", javax.persistence.Tuple.class)
                                                    .getResultList();
result.get(0).get("Project");
```

I'm getting this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class javax.persistence.Tuple ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; javax.persistence.Tuple is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @7a9273a8)
```

So it seems to be returning `List` of `Object`s instead of `Tuple`s. Is `Tuple` not supported by EclipseLink or what is the problem?

Debugger shows it's actually a `Vector` of `Object`s:

[image]

I'm using TomEE 8 which uses EclipseLink 2.7.4.v20190115 for JPA. I could try with JPA Criteria Query but I'm converting from SQL and it would be easier to convert it to JPQL.

**Edit 1**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59840498/1827453) is an answer from writer of the linked article which also suggests this should work.

**Edit 2**

EclipseLink [issue](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/issues/778) created.

**Edit 3**

Luckily it works with JPA Criteria Query (`CriteriaBuilder#createTupleQuery()`). It's more work to convert SQL to that but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

A query with projection returns always `List<Object[]>`

As long as you don't use constructor expression with

```
select new x.y.Tuple(f.Id, f.Project) from FirewallRequest f
```

But then you need a Tuple with a constructor that matches the projection.

Comment: So the code in the linked example (which even has asserts) would never work?

Comment: It seems that EclipseLink does not support it.

Comment: OK that's what I thought, would work with Hibernate.

Comment: Oh I just see another issue. Is Project an Entity?

Comment: No, it's a String field in entity.

Comment: I tried with Hibernate and it works. Can you try to use the newest EclipseLink version?

Comment: That's quite new and it's bundled with TomEE. I can investigate.

Comment: I was able to upgrade to latest 2.7.6 with Maven dependency but it did not help.

Comment: Tried to switch to Hibernate but I always get `ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` in spite of having all required dependencies.