# How to return map with multiple sum in jpql jpa?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

Here is my query

```
select SUM(d.day) as totalDay, SUM(d.month) as totalMonth from record d where d.userId = ?1
Integer getRecod(Long id);
```

As the query is not returning integer, error occurs. What should i replace with integer?

Comment: There is not standard way of doing so, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371384/can-a-jpa-query-return-results-as-a-java-map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution 1:
Create a model with totalDay and totalMonth and create an all args constructor.

```
public class UserDataModel {
    Long totalDay;
    Long totalMonth;

    public UserDataModel(Long totalDay, Long totalMonth) {
        this.totalDay = totalDay;
        this.totalMonth = totalMonth;
    }
    
    //getter and setter
}
```

Change your query like

```
@Query(value = "select 
new com.package.UserDataModel(SUM(d.day) as totalDay, SUM(d.month) as totalMonth) 
from Record d where d.userId = ?1 ")
    UserDataModel getRecord(Long id);
```

Solution 2: using spring projection. Create an interface like this. Make sure to follow proper camcelCase.

```
public interface UserDataModelV2 {
    Long getTotalDay();
    Long getTotalMonth();
}
```

Change your moethod like this.

```
    @Query(value = "select " +
            " SUM(d.day) as totalDay, SUM(d.month) as totalMonth " +
            "from Record d where d.userId = ?1")
    List<UserDataModelV2> getRecord(Long id);
```

If you want to return a HashMap instead of a POJO, you can extend UserDataModel with hashMap and put data in the map in the constructor.

```
public class UserDataModel extends HashMap<String, Object>{
    Long totalDay;
    Long totalMonth;

    public UserDataModel(Long totalDay, Long totalMonth) {
        this.totalDay = totalDay;
        this.totalMonth = totalMonth;
        put("totalDay",totalDay); 
        put("totalMonth",totalMonth); 
    }
    
    //getter and setter
}
```

Or you can replace the Interface in Solution 2 with a Map<Stirng, Object>.

```
@Query(value = "select " +
            " SUM(d.day) as totalDay, SUM(d.month) as totalMonth " +
            "from Record d where d.userId = ?1")
    List<Map<Stirng, Object>> getRecord(Long id);
```

Comment: is it possible to return `Map<String, Integer>`  instead of `List<UserDataModelV2>` ? where map key would be totalDay and value would be the sum. I dont want to create object

Comment: you can extend the UserDataModel with HashMap , and populate the map in the constructor.

Comment: Yes you can use map instead of Userdatamodelv2, I have updated the ans.

Comment: All that i wanted is `List<Map<Stirng, Object>>` thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should replace `Integer` with `Object[]` :

`Object[] getRecod(Long id);`

because `SUM(d.day) as totalDay, SUM(d.month) as totalMonth` return two long value in array

Comment: is that ordered array? I mean do i always get first sum at array[0] and second sum at array[1]?  If not ordered then it will behave randomly

Comment: yes that ordered array, always totalDay at array[0] and totalMonth at array[1]