# Hibernate JPQL native query error - "column does not exist" and "Could not locate named parameter"

Tags: java

Hibernate JPQL native query error - "column does not exist" and "Could not locate named parameter"Hibernate JPQL native query error - "column does not exist" and "Could not locate named parameter"

Comment: The error is pretty clear. There is no column named `year`, which is right as your table definition doesn't have that. It has many columns but not one named `year`.

Comment: Your `create table` does show neither a column named `year` nor a clomun named `value`, so the error message is perfectly right. That you don't want to use the table as it's defined also goes to show that your database-design is way off...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the issues:

In the else there is the WHERE sido = :cityName so you have a mapping to cityName that can be done with query.setParameter("cityName", cityName); but this does not exist in the if, leading to your second error.

Your table does not contain a "value" column, nor does it contain a "year" column so it fails finding one, also if you create a year column, it will fail on the sum as there is no value.

Also the object returned by your query does not ressemble an AllScenario object, so the automatic mapping would likely fail.

**Solution**

What are those y2022, y2023... columns ? It looks like partitioning ? Maybe this should be reworked into the year column with a partition ? though the partition will not like the autoincrement on the id.

Then create a value column.

Finally create another object like "AggregatedAllValues" that as the year, sido, sgg, SUM(value) AS sumValue as attributes (sgg being null for the first query) like in [How to return map with multiple sum in jpql jpa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64569420/how-to-return-map-with-multiple-sum-in-jpql-jpa) or with manual mapping if you prefer

Also you might consider not doing an impl of the repository and leave an interface with two custom queries and do the if in the service calling them. That would spare the entityManager injection and errors in the query params